Count Number of Months String Contains Based on Criteria
I'm looking for a formula to provide me with a count of the number of months that meet certain criteria.
Here is an example of the cells that would need to be evaluated:



Months




2024 May, 2023 October, 2023 August, 2022 December, 2022 October


2024 February, 2023 August, 2023 May, 2022 December, 2022 October


2023 October, 2023 August, 2023 May, 2023 January, 2022 October


2024 May, 2024 March, 2024 February, 2023 January, 2022 October


2024 March, 2024 February, 2023 December, 2023 October, 2023 May


2023 October, 2023 August, 2023 June, 2023 May, 2022 October


2024 May, 2023 October, 2023 May, 2023 March, 2023 January


2023 August, 2023 May, 2023 January, 2022 October



The user will be selecting a month from a drop down. Let's say they select 2023 October. I will need the formula to count any cell that contains that month or newer. Result should look like this:



Months
Count




2024 May, 2023 October, 2023 August, 2022 December, 2022 October
2


2024 February, 2023 August, 2023 May, 2022 December, 2022 October
1


2023 October, 2023 August, 2023 May, 2023 January, 2022 October
1


2024 May, 2024 March, 2024 February, 2023 January, 2022 October
3


2024 March, 2024 February, 2023 December, 2023 October, 2023 May
4


2023 October, 2023 August, 2023 June, 2023 May, 2022 October
1


2024 May, 2023 October, 2023 May, 2023 March, 2023 January
2


2023 August, 2023 May, 2023 January, 2022 October
0



Other Notes:

The months will always been in order (Recent to Oldest)
Format of months will always be 4-Digit Year, Full Month Name
Location of user selected month: Let's say Settings!A1
Location of cells to be evaluated: Data!A2:A
Location of cells with counts: Data!B2:B



Here's one approach you may test out:
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,let(Λ,split(Σ,", ",),countif(Λ,">="&A1)))))



Adjust ranges in the formula as needed in your sheet


This is amazing. I've never seen lambda() before. I feel like I'm reading a different language here. Well it worked and it was pretty efficient from what I can tell. No problem calculating across 50K cells. Thanks!

Here's a follow-up. Would there be a way to extract those months and leave only those that don't meet the criteria in another column?

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Understood. Perhaps I will pose a new question. Let me get this sorted out and if I can't figure it out on my own I will post a new question.
